# Build linux render farm in order to render adobe premiere projects

Tags: premiere, video-editor, adobe, linux

I edit my videos on Adobe Premiere (or even Edius) and I want to build a linux based render farm for rendering my projects.

The concepts I've found in my research are 'render manager' and 'frame serving' which won't do a cross platform stuff in the way I desire or please tell me that I'm mistaken!

How do I set up a render farm for this task?

*Note that I have a linux server which means it doesn't have a Graphical User Interface.*

Comment: Perhaps that is because that I have not got my answer and unfortunately not so many people had opinions about the topic.  by the 'not possible answer' is not really believable . I don't know ,may be developers have not accomplished something that does it!

Comment: Don't take it personal. Sure, undestand it. But the idea / rule of stackoverflow is to point out duplicates. As I said, might be better to edit your first one. I'd like to help but I don't have so much time now. BTW: opinions are off-topic ;) Good Luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using ffmpeg. Here are the steps:

1. First do steps of the second method ("Use a frameserver") [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/PremierePro).
2. Beginning this step you should be streaming your Premier timeline through Debugmode and Avisynth on a specific IP and port. Now open a command line and run this ffmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -i frameserver.avs -f mpegts  tcp://[IP address of your server]:[open port on your server]`

By running this command, you are sending the Avisynth output (streaming) to a destination machine (your Linux server) through ffmpeg.
After this step all you have to do on the client server (where you edit your videos) is done. Next, set up the server side.

3. On the server (your Linux server), make sure you have ffmpeg installed and run the following command:
   `ffmpeg -i tcp://[your server IP]:[The same port you entered in step 2]?listen -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 4 output2.mp4`

Through this command, ffmpeg will be listening on a specified IP and port and receiving sent packets and encode them with your favorite options!